# Amazon EC latency SLA

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, latency

Looks like Amazon EC2 doesn't provides any **latency** SLA. What is the reason behind not providing it?

Also in general I see that none of cloud providers provide latency SLA on any of their services.

Answer (score 0):

All good providers will do everything they can to ensure their cloud hosting solutions run smoothly, but it's impossible to give a latency SLA on a virtual machine, because they are just that - virtual machine that **share** resources with other virtual machines on the same host.